# Problem with greek letters

Tags: greek

I need to write in my document some greek letter (outside any formulas). What do you suggest me? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it happens several times in your document it might be worthwile to use greek babel and the commands `\textlatin` and `\textgreek` as to switch.

Text can be input both by replacement characters as well as in unicode.

For more info consult the babel-greek documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\section{Latin Text:}

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz


\greektext
\section{Έλληνες κείμενο -- 'Ellhnec ke'imeno}

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

\latintext
Latin Text again

\end{document}
```

Comment: there is this error

Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:Î not set up for use with LaTeX ...½ÎµÏ ÎºÎµÎ¯Î¼ÎµÎ½Î¿ -- 'Ellhnec ke'imeno}

Comment: @ryuk This means the greek unicode characters I used in the second `\section` are getting broken when you copied and pasted the MWE into your editor. Make sure they appear as "real" greek in your editor and make sure you are saving the file as UTF8.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest remains compiling with `XeLaTeX`, using an open type font with Greek letters and typesetting directly Greek letters:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

 Pythagoras and Euclid

 Πυθαγόρας και Ευκλείδης.

\end{document}
```

[image]