# How to activate on LaTeX greek and latin characters

Tags: characters

I try to use LaTeX writing paper Greek and English text, *without* using separate commands for Greek or English (like: `\begin{otherlanguage}{greek}`), but using both Greek and Latin characters under the same command.

I found the [`auto-greek`](http://www.eelvex.net/latex-auto-greek/) package but I did't manage to install it on my macbook.

```
\usepackage{auto-greek}
```

Note that I have every font that supports Greek and Latin characters!

Comment: You need to tell LaTeX that the language changes, how else will LaTeX know how to hyphenate?

Comment: Related, at least: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=27015

Comment: @Johannes_B What the auto-greek package seems to use is a combined set of (probably American) English hyphenation patterns and Greek ones. I guess this works because the languages don't share a common script.

Answer (score 2):

Use can write Greek directly with the `alphabeta` package.

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage [utf8]           {inputenc}
\usepackage [greek, english] {babel}
\usepackage                  {alphabeta}

\begin {document}

Text in Greek: τίνι ἢ  γὰρ, ἄμφω

\end {document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way might be using XeLaTeX like in [this answer by Bernhard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279446/63226). I will just copy his MWE (use UTF-8 as character encoding when saving this as a new file):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

 Pythagoras and Euclid

 Πυθαγόρας και Ευκλείδης.

\end{document}
```

You can adjust the used font with `\setmainfont{font}` (keep in mind that this will use your system's ttf or otf-fonts not the ordinary LaTeX ones.

Comment: You can replace both fontspec and setmaintfont commands if you are using xelatex by using the package libertine. So, \usepackage{libertine} will be better.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following solution is working:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek, english]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{betababel}

\begin{document}
Philosophische Anthropologie\\
\textbf{Die Lehre (\bcode{lo/gos}) vom ,,Menschen'' (\bcode {a)/ntropos})}.  
Urspr"ungleich wollte man den Menschen als ,,Maschine'', wie ein Uhrwerk
betrachten     und erkl"aren, Kant versuchte, die Anthropologie zu einer 
ordentlichen" Disziplin     zu 
\end{document}
```

I have the Mac OSX and installed texlive-latex with Port.